# Characteristic Polynomial of a Linear Transformation Proof

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Let $T: V\to V$ be a linear transformation of the $n$-dimensional vector space $V$, and suppose there is $v\in V$ such that the set $B=\{v, Tv, T^2 v,\ldots, T^{n-1} v\}$ is a basis of $V$. Let $f$ be the characteristic polynomial of $T$.

Show that $f(T)(v)=0$.

I understand $f(T)=a_0 I+a_1T+a_2 T^2+\cdots+a_n T^n$

so $f(T)(v)=a_0 v+ a_1 Tv+ a_2 T^2 v+ \cdots +a_n T^n v$ 
but I'm  not sure where to go from here..thanks!

Comment: There's no way you're going to be able to do this without using the definition of the characteristic polynomial. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I understand that the roots of the characteristic polynomial are the eigenvalues of the transformation and that the characteristic polynomial is generated by det(A-Iλ)=0 but I guess I'm a little lost on how to apply this to a mxn matrix as opposed to a square one. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Here's a beginning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem $\qquad$